# Passing variables from one Python file to another?

Tags: python, selenium, variables

So basically i made a little selenium script and i want to save the pass word and email in a different file for easy editing.
For some reason passing the variables is not working and i cant make heads and tails. i get this error:
`unused import statement`(when i hover over the import line `from Details import *`)
I still struggle a bit with Python and would love if you dont bash me for a probably obvious mistake :P

Edit: the programm itsself works fine its just when i try to pass variables that it messes up.

```js
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from Details import *

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = "https://discordapp.com/channels/530588470905929729/538868623981412362"
driver.get(url)
email = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@type='email']")))
email.send_keys(email)

password = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@type='password']")))
password.send_keys(password + Keys.ENTER)

sleep(5)

textbox = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//textarea[@placeholder='Message #bot-commands']")))
textbox.send_keys("!work" + Keys.ENTER)

sleep(30)

driver.quit()
```

this is Details.py :

```js
password = "Password"
email = "Email@email.com"
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: What error do you run into?

Comment: Sry guys, i edited it

Answer (score 2):

You use:

```
from Details import *
```

And Details contains a variable password. But your other code also has a different variable password.

Try:

```
import Details

imported_password = Details.password
```

Comment: Ty that was so obvious haha

Comment: Often it’s the simple things that get overlooked and can drive you crazy :-).

Comment: For future questions: You can also mark answers as “answered”. For simple questions this will spare other users the time to look at the question to see if they can help.